# Whats the highest (approximate) request rate DRb can handle?

Tags: ruby, drb

I'm using DRb for relatively infrequent interprocess communication now, but I'm worried that it may not be able to handle the load if my service grows, especially given things like spawining a new thread to deal with every request. Anybody have experience dealing with DRb's upper limits and can tell me at approximately what load it started causing problems? what would be a better way of dealing with this, perhaps a thread running sinatra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a performance test on it, and test for yourself.

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |x|    
    x.report {100000.times {"Do DRb request here"}}
end
```